# Mutual Induction "Game"

Tags: prime-numbers, induction, puzzle

The specifics of my assignment are as follows:

The following simple game can be played by two players. First, mutually agree on a starting number and the player who will take the first turn. On your turn, "split" the number into three prime numbers. (That is, name three prime numbers that sum to your number.) Your opponent must then select one of the three named primes to be the next number, and they take the next turn. If, on your turn, you are unable to split your number into three primes, you lose.

Gameplay Example I take the first turn with 23 as my number. I can split it into five possible combinations: 2+2+19, 3+3+17, 3+7+13, 5+5+13, or 5+7+11. I choose 5+7+11. My opponent selects 11 as the next number and splits it into 3+3+5. I select 5, but I cannot split it into the sum of three primes and so I lose.

If we want to consider all possible paths of choices, there are exponentially many to keep track of. However, we can assume that both players are trying to win, so if player A has a choice between making a move that guarantees their loss and one which guarantees their win, we can safely assume they will choose to win.

For each starting number, determine which player wins the game under optimal play. Prove that your analysis is correct using induction. You will probably want to use structural induction for this problem.

I thought this would be very simple to solve, but I'm struggling with it. Without loss of generality, let's assume Person 1 (P1) always goes first. In order for P1 to win, they need to pick a "winning" number that can be divided into 3 "losing" numbers. For example, let's consider the first few primes as starting numbers and see if P1 wins:
2:L (NA)
3:L (NA)
5:L (NA)
7:W (2+2+3)
11:W (3+3+5)
13:W (5+5+3)
17:L (2+2+13)
19:L (3+3+13)
23:W (3+3+17)
29:W (5+5+19)
31:L (7+7+17) (Two winning primes and 1 losing prime)
37:W (3+3+31)
41:W (19+19+3)
43:W (19+19+5)
47:L (17+17+13)
53:W (3+3+47)

There is no discernable pattern that I can see in the wins/losses or in the numbers themselves. If someone could provide insight into this I would be very thankful.

Comment: It seems weird that the game starts by both players agreeing to a specific starting point: the starting number and which player starts first. If one of the players has a winning strategy given that starting point, why would the other player ever agree to that starting point?

Comment: On the one hand, I agree with the comment of @Bram28.  On the other hand, the original question can be *salvaged* (for example) by requiring that person-1 must go first, and that the starting point will be some random number between 10,000 and 100,000.  Then, one could ask what the probability is of person-1 winning, assuming perfect play by both parties.

Comment: +1 to your posting.  Personally, I would be surprised if the question can be solved without computer-assisted brute force.  Certainly, that approach will solve every number less than $~1000.~$  Whether such an approach is viable, on a vanilla home pc, for every number less than $~100000~$ is another question.

Comment: Yeah, who goes first and the number selected aren't important. All that matters is that a number is selected, and someone goes first (aka they actually play a game)

Comment: Note that they can also split the number in 2 winning and 1 losing (which ends up being a losing position). EG For 16, we split it into 2+7+7. $\quad$ Also, you should generate the list for all integers, not jus the primes -> Can you update it accordingly?

Comment: @IndigoMouse Are you sure they want you to determine which player has optimal play for each number?  Or are they just looking for a proof that for any starting number one of the players is guaranteed to have a winning strategy, no mater how smart the other player is?

Comment: @Bram28 Perhaps I am missing something.  The very structure of the game indicates to me that it is completely solvable via brute force, in the same way that [chess endgame tablebases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endgame_tablebase) have completely solved any chess position within the tablebase's umbrella.  It is hard for me to even envision that the game is not (theoretically) completely solvable  for any positive integer.  I use the term *theoretically* to indicate that limited computer resources will place an upper bound on which integers can be solved.

Comment: @Bram28 The assignment's goals are "Determine which player is victorious for each possible starting number (player 1 or player 2). Prove that your determination is correct using induction." That's why I added the WLOG assume P1 always goes first. Theoretically, there's some way to solve it, I might just be going at it the completely wrong way. In addition, I noticed that it goes 3 losses, 3 wins, 2 losses, 2 wins, 1 loss, 1 win, although when I checked the next 4 primes I got 41: W, 43: W, 47: L, 53: W which implies to me that this pattern doesn't continue

Comment: @user2661923 I agree .. it indeed *seems* like the game is solvable for any integer, and it is indeed *hard to envision* how it wouldn't be.  And the nice thing is that there is a fairly simple (though non-trivial) inductive proof that *in fact* the game is solvable for any number. So I was thinking that maybe that was the assignment, rather than spelling out or producing some kind of closed formula for whether some number leads to a win or a loss for player 1 (assuming both payers play perfectly) ... because *that* seems like a real nasty problem.

Comment: @Bram28 Is there a link to the proof? It may not answer the original question, but maybe there's something in it that could help

Comment: @IndigoMouse I think it's a good exercise in strong induction for you to do. Like I said, it's not trivial ... but it's also not difficult.

Comment: @Bram28 Actually, that might not be necessary. I messed up my earlier math and will update the original list. All primes appear to be able to be represented in a form (x+x+y) with their winning/losing status being the opposite of y's (for a losing prime x). I don't know if this is true for all primes, but I'll look into it further because it seems promising

Comment: After writing some code I've learned in the first 10,000 integers, 1,230 are prime and 421 are losing primes